# How do I use React setState() to set the state to a specific value that is a constant?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

```
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  let newNumber = 200;

  useEffect(() => {
    setNumber(number = newNumber);
  }, [])
```

I believe I'm misunderstanding something about how state works in React.js. If I set the above code's setNumber(number + 1) section to '+ 1' like so then number becomes '201' but if I set it to '= newNumber' I get a 'TypeError: Assignment to constant variable' error. Why is this the case? And shouldn't the error be something else since newNumber isn't a constant variable using the 'const' tag?

Comment: In this case it is much simplier if you use `const [number, setNumber] = useState(200)`. Also `setNumber` sets the value for `number` if you pass as an argument.

Comment: my initial value has to be something else though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setNumber` function accepts a value you want to set your state to. So If you want to set number to the value of newNumber you would do `setNumber(newNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use setNumber like

```
useEffect(() => {
    setNumber(newNumber);
  }, [])
```

or better just in initial expression

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your values inside `setNumber` function.

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  let newNumber = 200;

  useEffect(() => {
    setNumber(newNumber);
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` describe the state, it can be an object, string, boolean and a number. In case its a primitive data i.e not an object, you just need to pass the value while updating it as follows:

```
setStateVal(5); // here 5 will become the new state
```

In case your state is an object, you need to pass the updated state object as follows:

```
setStateVal({val: 5});
```

In no case you use `=` operator.